# Effect of ghost classes on method caches in Ruby 2.1+

Tags: ruby, caching

When extending an instance, like so:

```
class Hello
  def say
    "hello"
  end
end

module World
  def say
    super + " world"
  end
end

greet = Hello.new
greet.extend(World)

greet.say
#=> "hello world"
```

A ghost class is inserted in the ancestor tree of `greet` with World as the first member of the tree:

```
ghostclass = class << greet; self; end
#=> #<Class:#<Hello:0x007fb67680c300>>
ghostclass.ancestors
#=> [#<Class:#<Hello:0x007fb67680c300>>, World, Hello, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Since Ruby 2.1, [when changing a class hierarchy, cache invalidations only happen for the class in question and any subclasses](https://mensfeld.pl/2015/04/ruby-global-method-cache-invalidation-impact-on-a-single-and-multithreaded-applications/)

However, I haven't been able to confirm that the method cache is still intact for the original hierarchy, for example:

```
greet = Hello.new
greet.say # cache hit??
#=> "hello"
```

Also, how far does the interpreter really have to look to find `#say` on the ghost class? Would a cache really be important?

FYI, I'm not trying to micro-optimize performance, I've already done preliminary measurements of similar real-world code and found it to have no real impact.

Still, I'm curious about how exactly this works, and I haven't been able to confirm by simple googling or asking around in the Ruby forums I have access to (and I don't have access to Ruby Core).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I get it. You expected to return "hello world" instead of "hello", right?

Comment: Yeah, I could have expressed that better. I expected it to say "hello", but what's unclear is how to tell that method dispatch for finding `#say` got a hit on the method cache, which you would hope because the `greet` instance wasn't extended. In Ruby v < 2.1 this would not be true because extending the instance would have busted the global method cache, but in v >= 2.1 I would hope not, but I'd like to know for sure.